# Search Japanese String message in .Properties file

Tags: java, localization, properties-file

I have a String message in japanese language. 
I want to search and compare it with the property file with key and value pair and return Pass if there is a match with the value(in japanese). In property file, value is in doble byte , which needs to convert to japanese before comparison. Dont know how to do that. Writing down .property file below code.

System.out.println(sMessage);

```
if(sMessage != null){

// Read Property file using file reader 
// In property file, value is in doble byte , which needs to convert to japanese before comparison. Dont know how to do that.

                 BufferedReader br = null;
                    String strLine = "";
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("C:\\common-test\\common-test\\translationtest\\messages_ja.properties"));
                        strLine = br.readLine().toString();
                        System.out.println(strLine);
                                br.readLine();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.err.println("Unable to find the file: fileName");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("Unable to read the file: fileName");
                    }

                    if(Arrays.equals(sMessage.getBytes(), strLine.getBytes() ))
                    {
                        ReportResults("Pass", "Toaster message for Invalid Credentials" + sMessage + " equals test from property file: " + strLine,false);
                    }
                    else{
                        ReportResults("Fail",  "Toaster message for Invalid Credentials" + sMessage + " does NOT equals test from property file: " + strLine,true);
                    }


                //ReportResults("FAIL", "Login Failed: " + sMessage, true);
                //Assert.fail("Login failed: " + sMessage);
            }
```

.properties file attached below

```
WM-SM-BE-0001=\u5FC5\u8981\u306A\uFF8A\uFF9F\uFF97\uFF92\uFF70\uFF80{0}\u3092\u5165\u529B    \u3057\u3066\u4E0B\u3055\u3044
WM-SM-BE-0002=\u7121\u52B9\u306A\u8A8D\u8A3C\u3002
WM-SM-BE-0003=\uFF95\uFF70\uFF7B\uFF9E\uFF70\u306F\u65E2\u306B\u5B58\u5728\u3002
WM-SM-BE-0004=\uFF9B\uFF70\uFF99\u540D\u306F\u65E2\u306B\u5B58\u5728\u3002
```

Comment: Do you wan't to convert the escaped unicode characters back to actual characters?

Comment: Yes Martin, i want to convert and compare them with the string

Comment: do you want to compare your string with the full line of the property file (key and value) or only with the value?

Answer (score 1):

A properties file is always encoded as ISO-8859-1. So if you want to properly and reliably read the data your self, you need to specify it:

```
 br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\common-test\\common-test\\translationtest\\messages_ja.properties"),"ISO-8859-1"));
```

But that's if you want to compare your string with the full first line of the properties file. If you just want to compare the value, for a given key, use the `Properties` class, that does the proper reading for you.

Comment: HI JP, Thanks for the hint. Can you please help me by providing an example on how to write it using Properties class.

Comment: Just use Properties.load(InputStream)